# using Protobuf-Net with f# class

Tags: f#, protobuf-net

I'm playing f# and making a server program for fun.

I think I can solve this question by using f# to access c# data class but I want to try the f# syntax.

I got f# record with `[<CLIMutable>]` works but f# class got error

my test code :

```
open System
open System.IO
open ProtoBuf

[<ProtoContract; Serializable>]
type Point (m_x : int, m_y : int) = 
    [<ProtoMember(1)>]
    member this.x = m_x
    [<ProtoMember(2)>]
    member this.y = m_y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let p : Point = new Point(10, 10)
    let out = Console.OpenStandardOutput()
    Serializer.Serialize<Point>(out, p)
    printfn "finish"
    0
```

and I got following output:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot apply changes to property Program+Point.x
  at ProtoBuf.Serializers.PropertyDecorator.SanityCheck (ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel model, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, IProtoSerializer tail, System.Boolean& writeValue, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean allowInternal) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ProtoBuf.Serializers.PropertyDecorator..ctor (ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel model, System.Type forType, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property, IProtoSerializer tail) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know much about Protobuf I suspect that its serialization cannot assign a new value to class Point fields because in F# they are immutable by default. You could change your class definition to use mutable fields/properties:

```
open System
open System.IO
open ProtoBuf

[<ProtoContract; Serializable>]
type Point (m_x : int, m_y : int) = 
    let mutable vx = 0
    let mutable vy = 0
    do
        vy <- m_y
        vx <- m_x

    [<ProtoMember(1)>]
    member this.x with get() = vx and set v = vx <- v
    [<ProtoMember(1)>]
    member this.y with get() = vy and set v = vy <- v
```

Maybe it'll help.
Also if F# record with [] works then maybe it is easier to use records? Records in F# support members as well as classes.

Comment: I just found this myself. I forgot the setter function. Thanks for your quick reply.